# How can I replace text in a xml file from a source area within the same document?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Fairly new to notepad++ and regex in general and have managed to do most of my tasks but now I'm stuck.

I have lots of xml files which i need to replace text in but the replacement text is also within the xml file.

Anybody know how to do this?

See attachement screen shot but code is below:

```
<button name="Button2" height="39" width="124" left="211" top="422" visible="true" wallpaper="false" toolTipText="" exposeToVba="notExposed" isReferenceObject="false" style="3d" captureCursor="false" highlightOnFocus="true" tabIndex="1">
        <command pressAction="" repeatAction="" releaseAction="abz" repeatRate="0.25"/><button 
name="Button4" height="39" width="124" left="211" top="422" visible="true" wallpaper="false" toolTipText="" exposeToVba="notExposed" isReferenceObject="false" style="3d" captureCursor="false" highlightOnFocus="true" tabIndex="1">
<command pressAction="" repeatAction="" releaseAction=" abz" repeatRate="0.25"/>

Private Sub Button2_Released()
ScreenName = "test screen" 
Private Sub Button4_Released()
ScreenName = "test screen info"
[enter image description here][1]
```

See screen shot, I’m trying to replace the green highlighted text in the button expression with the  information from the variable names via a find and replace function where the blue and red text is the matching parameters and the green is the replacement location and the yellow is the replacement source

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there will be any space between your button and command nodes but something like this is what you want.

Find:

```
<button name="([^"]+)" height="39" width="124" left="211" top="422" visible="true" wallpaper="false" toolTipText="" exposeToVba="notExposed" isReferenceObject="false" style="3d" captureCursor="false" highlightOnFocus="true" tabIndex="1"><command pressAction="" repeatAction="" releaseAction="[^"]*"
```

Replace:

```
 <button name="$1" height="39" width="124" left="211" top="422" visible="true" wallpaper="false" toolTipText="" exposeToVba="notExposed" isReferenceObject="false" style="3d" captureCursor="false" highlightOnFocus="true" tabIndex="1"><command pressAction="" repeatAction="" releaseAction="$1"
```

It will replace the releaseaction value with the first capture group $1. (button name value)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* search and replace repeatedly this patterns:

Find: `(<button name=")(.*?)(".*?releaseAction=").*?"(.*?Private Sub )\2(_Released.*?ScreenName = ")(.*?)(?=")`

Replace: `$1$2$3$6$4$2$5$6`

With `. matches newline`checked.

But I really do not recommend that.

**Explanation:**

The parts in parentheses are called "capture groups" and can be referred to in the search as well as in the replace expression.

```
(<button name=")             group1     matches the part before the button name
(.*?)                        group2     matches the button name 
(".*?releaseAction=")        group3     matches the part between the button name
                                        and the part to be replaced
.*?                                     matches the part that will be replaced
(".*?Private Sub )           group4     matches the rest of the xml up to the next occurence
                                        of the button name 
\2                                      reference to group 2 (the button name)
(_Released.*?ScreenName = ") group5     matches the part up to the screen name
(.*?)                        group6     matches the screen name                      
(?=")                        non capturing look ahead, makes sure the capture group
```